# how use OnItemLongClick in list view in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am developing an app in xamarin android. In that app, I am displaying a custom list. I want to display a pop up using `listView_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)` In that pop up I need to show two options **Update** and **delete**. And depending upon the user selection I want do further processing.

Can anyone please give me examples which I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply want to do something in the `EventHandler` you can do simple stuff like:

```
var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.MyListView);
listView.ItemLongClick += listView_ItemLongClick;

private void listView_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Now that you can react to `LongClicks` you now want to display a "pop-up". In this case you probably want something like a `Dialog` (All API levels) or a `PopupMenu` (API level 11 and up).

Using the `PopupMenu` is fairly simple. First you need to define a `popupmenu.xml` file, which needs to live in `Resources/menu/`, for creation of the items in the `PopupMenu`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/pm_update"
          android:title="Update" />    
    <item android:id="@+id/pm_delete"
          android:title="Delete" />  
</menu>
```

Next up you need to add a simple piece of code to your `EventHandler` for the `ItemLongClick` event:

```
var menu = new PopupMenu(this, (View)sender);
menu.Inflate(Resource.Menu.popupmenu);
menu.MenuItemClick += (s, a) =>
{
    switch (a.Item.ItemId)
    {
        case Resource.Id.pm_update:
            // update stuff
            break;
        case Resource.Id.pm_delete:
            // delete stuff
            break;
    }
};
menu.Show();
```

If you want a `Dialog` instead there are LOADS of samples out there on how to make those.

Comment: I was reading your [blog](http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/02/using-dialogs-in-mono-for-android.html?m=1) ... there you said Dialog is deprecated in API level 8 and 13, you have not mention anything about popup menu. is that also been deprecated?

Comment: You obviously did not read it through. I mentioned a couple of methods in `Activity` are deprecated, not `Dialog` itself.

Comment: does popupmenu xml has to be in Menu folder? will it be if i generate it in Layout? also getting bellow error :

**The type or namespace name 'PopupMenu' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Do i have to add any reference>

Comment: As I wrote it was added in API level 11, hence your project needs to target that, which you can change in the Project properties. The popupmenu.xml needs to be in the menu folder, yes. Then you will need to rebuild it before it is picked up in the Resource.Designer.cs file.

Comment: I am getting **'InsuranceReminder.Resource.Menu' does not contain a definition for 'pm_update'** and **'InsuranceReminder.Resource.Menu' does not contain a definition for 'pm_delete'**  can you please help?

Comment: Where did you put it, and did you rebuild the project?

Comment: I created a new folder called Menu under Resources. Inside Menu I created popupmenu.xml and copied whatever xml you have given in your example above. I built it. Still getting same error.
Do I have to do explicit comparison or whatever you have given is sufficient?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38507/discussion-between-cheesebaron-and-pratik-gaikwad)